# How to stream music in aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'd like to stream music with aspx, but i dont know how to start!
My general idea is that users, can have their one playlists, and upload their musics, but i dont know how can they hear their own musics trough the website.
The second idea is that the most voted playlist is streamed online for the people who want to hear!

Comment: This question is too broadly scoped.  "*[If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)*"  You'll have to do some research on your own, and come back to tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once users upload their audio files, you can use the HTML5 [`<audio>`](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3920991/HTML5-Primer-How-To-Use-the-Audio-Tag.htm) tag. [AudioJS](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) is a library that will make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for education purpose?  Otherwise, there are a few IceCast / ShoutCast offerings out there that already have some of this functionality.